# Preprocess less to permit whitespace sensitive syntax

Tags: javascript, regex, less

I was having a look at a [github issue in less project](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2170) which is trying to permit whitespace sensitivity instead of braces akin to stylus.

I started (quite brutally) hacking together a possible proposed solution so that instead of replacing the less parser completely, the `even-less` (whitespace sensitive version of less) can be pre-processed into less, which can then be parsed as usual.

```js
// make input string
var src = [
".navbar",
"  display:block;",
"  .item",
"    float:left;",
"    text-decoration:none;",
"    &:hover",
"      text-decoration:underline;"
].join("\n")

function parseEvenLess(src){

    // split intput string into lines
    var lines = src.split("\n");

    // declare variables to handle output, and tracking of indents
    var out = [], lastIndent = "", currentIndent = "", extras = [];

    // loop through lines, then each indent added during loop
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length + extras.length; i++){
        // get the current line (from lines or added indents)
        var line = lines[i] || extras[i-lines.length];
        // get the current indentation string
        currentIndent = line.match(/^\s*/)[0];
        // attempt to handle ommision of `:` and `;`
        // must be done retrospectively (on previous line) to disambiguate `element:right` as selector or rule definition
        if(i && currentIndent.length <= lastIndent.length){
            out[i-1] = out[i-1].replace(/^(\s*[^\s:]+)(\s*:\s*|\s+)(\S[^;]+);?$/g, "$1: $3;");
        }
        // if we have increased the indentation
        if(lastIndent.length < currentIndent.length){
            // add an opening brace
            out[i-1] += " {";
            // slip the indent onto the indentations array to handle insertion of closing braces
            extras.unshift(lastIndent);
        }
        // if we have decreased indentation
        if(lastIndent.length > currentIndent.length){
            // prepend the line with a closing brace (indented)
            line = currentIndent+"}" + line;
        }
        // add the line to the final output array
        out.push(line);
        // store reference to currentIndent for use in next iteration
        lastIndent = currentIndent;
    }

    // return the final string
    return out.join("\n");

}

var finalOutput = [];

// works with single block
finalOutput.push( parseEvenLess([
".navbar",
"  display:block;",
"  .item",
"    float:left;",
"    text-decoration:none;",
"    &:hover",
"      text-decoration:underline;"
].join("\n")) );

// breaks with multiple blocks
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
finalOutput.push( parseEvenLess([
".navbar",
"  display:block;",
"  .item",
"    float:left;",
"    text-decoration:none;",
"    &:hover",
"      text-decoration:underline;",
".navbar",
"  display:block;",
"  .item",
"    float:left;",
"    text-decoration:none;",
"    &:hover",
"      text-decoration:underline;"
].join("\n")) );

document.getElementById("out").innerText = finalOutput.join("\n\n...\n\n");
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

My solution, besides being a horrific hack from start to end, breaks when there are multiple blocks. I don't really want to add more hacks to what is already a giant hack to address this - and I am sure there is a far more elegant solution - perhaps some kind of recursive function aware of it's current indentation instead of tracking and referring to previous line... or perhaps a two pass method, firstly organising input into blocks, and indentation groups, and then looping through them in second pass.

How should I approach this problem to have a more robust solution.

Comment: Not sure if it's correct according to their "on-topic", but since this is working code, you might look at posting this to [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan well, it works for a single block, but breaks if you add another block

Comment: If your question is about why it breaks on multiple blocks, perhaps that should be the question you end with ;).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan well, my question is why it breaks on multiple blocks, but I am starting to realise it is really an XY problem. The code I started with, worked fine for basic case, but each time I add code to try to handle more scenarios (like handling omission of `:` and `;`) there seems to be no elegant way to do it, revealing the deficiency in the underlying structure of my solution.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I edited the question to highlight the error a bit more

Comment: Okay. I don't have the time to dig into it right now. I just happened to see this on the front page and thought it was interesting... You might take a look at [how Stylus does it](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus), as was mentioned in that github issue...